# If string equals multiple string matches

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

So I've been running the below JavaScript code

```js
const getUserChoice = userInput => {
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();
  if (userInput === 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors') {
    return userInput
  } else {
    console.log('Error: please give relevant input \'rock\' \'paper\' or \'scissors\'.')
  }
}

getUserChoice('spock')
console.log(getUserChoice('paper'))
```

The code does correctly print out paper but it doesn't print the console.log error from the else conditional on the first call of the function with 'spock'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a common mistake, you **cannot** nest that way:

<s>`userInput === 'rock' || 'paper' || 'scissors'`</s>

you need to :

```js
if ( userInput === 'rock' || userInput === 'paper' || userInput === 'scissors' ) {
```

or if you want with a little [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for case insensitive `i`:

```js
if ( /^(rock|paper|scissors)$/i.test(userInput) ) {
```

or if you like Arrays than using [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
if ( ["rock", "paper", "scissors"].includes(userInput) ) {
```